# What are the tax implications of a normal sale of a house?

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate

What are the tax implications of a normal sale of a house, where the owner would make a "profit"?   Does it make any difference if the house is owner occupied and for how long they have owned the house?

Answer (score 5):

A single owner can have a gain up to $250K with no federal tax consequences. $500K for a couple. Above that, it's a capital gain. They must have lived in the home for 2 of the 5 years prior to the sale, else the numbers may scale back, if allowed at all.

If it was not owner occupied, the above is ignored, a rental has rules far more complicated, as the property must be depreciated during the time it was owned, and often there's a gain to be taxed for the fact that depreciation lowers the basis each year.

Edit - if the 2 years is not met see [Reduced Maximum Exclusion](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p523/ar02.html#en_US_2012_publink1000200747) for possible partial exclusion depending on cause of sale.

Comment: What are the numbers scaled back to if the occupancy is less than two years?

Comment: Edited my answer to include reference.

Comment: The scaling back is for only very limited circumstances, for most it just disappears.

Comment: @littleadv - edited my wording a bit to your comment.